# TextToSpeech android API 22 not playing audio

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am using text to speech engine in my App. It works fine on emulator Nexus 6 with API 23 and higher. But on emulator Nexus 6 with API 22 it does not speak.
Both emulators use Pico TTS as preferred engine.

My activity layout contains only one button "Speak".
This is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextToSpeech mTTS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button speakBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speak();
            }
        });

        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                    }

                    mTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.d("TTS", "onStart called, utteranceId = " + utteranceId);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.d("TTS", "onDone called, utteranceId = " + utteranceId);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.d("TTS", "onError called, utteranceId = " + utteranceId);
                    }
                });

                } else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void speak() {
       Log.d("TTS", "speak() method called");
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "greeting");

       mTTS.speak("hello", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
    }
}
```

This is all logs from emulator Nexus 6 API 22:

02-18 13:54:09.942 9739-9739/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system

02-18 13:54:09.943 9739-9739/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?

02-18 13:54:09.943 9739-9739/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

02-18 13:54:09.961 9739-9748/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

02-18 13:54:09.961 9739-9748/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active

02-18 13:54:09.992 9739-9739/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

02-18 13:54:10.001 9739-9739/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

02-18 13:54:10.001 9739-9739/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

02-18 13:54:10.064 9739-9739/? I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.svox.pico

02-18 13:54:10.072 9739-9757/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

02-18 13:54:10.074 9739-9739/? D/Atlas: Validating map...

02-18 13:54:10.093 9739-9739/? I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}

02-18 13:54:10.096 9739-9758/? I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}

02-18 13:54:10.111 9739-9757/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

02-18 13:54:10.111 9739-9757/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

02-18 13:54:10.128 9739-9757/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae434e20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2

02-18 13:54:10.131 9739-9757/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae434e20: ver 2 0

02-18 13:54:10.134 9739-9757/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0

02-18 13:54:10.174 9739-9757/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae434e20: ver 2 0

02-19 09:32:25.570 9739-9739/com.example.ttsapp D/TTS: speak() method called

Comment: The emulator is probably not using the same speech engine in API 22 as it is in API 23+ ... (PICO vs Google).  onError() is probably being called instead of onDone for some reason.  The code you have given is unnecessarily complex and incomplete (not rebuildable)... Why don't you make a very simple code example that just says "hello" and test to see if onError() is called with PICO... and if not, then slowly add the pieces of your code back until the problem occurs and presto! There is your answer.

Comment: Boober Bunz, thank you for your answer. Edited question text and code to make it simple and rebuildable. TTS still does not work on emulator Nexus 6 API 22, but works on Nexus 6 API 23.

Comment: could you post the log messages of your app, please? if something goes wrong, then you should see proper message in the logcat console.

Comment: Great! Now you could add an utterance progress listener and log ALL callbacks to see what's happening.

Comment: Added an utterance progress listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to solve the problem. Everything works if launch the emulator not via Debugging or Execution but from AVD Manager after starting Android Studio.